# How to keep specific time delay between the looping of an audio file in MediaPlayer in Android?

Tags: android-mediaplayer

I want to build an application for composing music. I have setup buttons that plays sounds but what i need here is to control the time delay after which the sound has to repeat. I have tried `setLooping` but it loops without any time delay.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to implement the looping by yourself with help of OnCompletionListener